# C# Regex Replacement Not Working

Tags: c#, regex, file, text

I'm trying to remove new lines from a text file. Opening the text file in notepad doesn't reveal the line breaks I'm trying to remove (it looks like one big wall of text), however when I open the file in sublime, I can see them.

[image]

In sublime, I can remove the pattern '\n\n' and then the pattern '\n(?!AAD)' no problem. However, when I run the following code, the resulting text file is unchanged:

```
        public void Format(string fileloc)
    {
        string str = File.ReadAllText(fileloc);
        File.WriteAllText(fileloc + "formatted", Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(str, "\n\n", ""), "\n(?!AAD)", ""));
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: on which platform are you running this? maybe your newlines are actually `\r\n`?

Comment: Put a `@` in front of the regex patterns.  Or double-backslash them.

Comment: Replacing \n with \r\n or \\n, as well as putting @ in-front of the patterns all result in no change.

Also, if these patterns would work in sublime, why would they not work in c#?

Comment: Share the exact file with us.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I can't. The file contains confidential client information. It's an export that contains client's names, emails, and addresses.

Comment: anonymize just two lines so we get an MCVE

Comment: Well, I cannot help much without exact input. A linebreak is `(?:\r?\n|\r)`. Matching 2 linebreaks - `(?:\r?\n|\r){2}`. Then, `\r?\n(?!AAD)` can be tried. Well, there are other possibilities, but again, too difficult to judge without the actual input data. Are you sure you check the right file?

Comment: @dlatikay http://www.filedropper.com/test_50

Comment: Anyway, my comment above is a generic way to match `CR`/`LF`/`CRLF` endings. There is just 1 "mistake": it should be `(?:\r?\n|\r)(?!AAD)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empirical solution. Opening your sample file in binary mode revealed that it contains 0x0D characters, which are carriage returns `\r`. So I came up with this (multiple lines for easier debugging):

```
public void Format(string fileloc)
{
    var str = File.ReadAllText(fileloc);
    var firstround = Regex.Replace(str, @"\r\r", "");
    var secondround = Regex.Replace(firstround, @"\r(?!AAD)", "");
    File.WriteAllText(fileloc + "formatted", secondround);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to spend hours trying to re-adjust the code for various types of linebreaks, here is a generic solution:

```
string str = File.ReadAllText(fileloc);
File.WriteAllText(fileloc + "formatted", 
    Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(str, "(?:\r?\n|\r){2}", ""), "(?:\r?\n|\r)(?!AAD)", "")
);
```

**Details**:

A linebreak can be matched with `(?:\r?\n|\r)`: an optional CR followed with a single obligatory LF. To match 2 consecutive linebreaks, a limiting quantifier can be appended - `(?:\r?\n|\r){2}`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this possibly a windows/linux mismatch? Try replacing '\r\n' instead.

Comment: or `Environment.Newline` to cover both in a portable way